# Django: accessing variable value from TemplateView

Tags: python, django

Say I have the following url that maps to a `TemplateView`:

```
url(r'^path/(?P<var1>\d+)/(?P<var2>\d+)/$', TemplateView.as_view('a_view.html'))
```

I thought in the template view `a_view.html` I could access the values of `var1` and `var2` as they're being captured and extracted into named parameters:

```
<!-- a_view.html -->

<p>var1 value = {{ var1 }}</p>
<p>var2 value = {{ var2 }}</p>
```

However, these values are blank when visiting `/path/10/89`. Why? How can I access them then? Would I need an explicit view?

Comment: You have to subclass `TemplateView` and implement `get_context_data()` as shown in https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview

Comment: You need to add the view kwargs to the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work.

Change you urls.py to use a named view:

```
url(r'^path/(?P<var1>\d+)/(?P<var2>\d+)/$', YourNamedView.as_view('a_view.html'))
```

Create a TemplateView and let it grab your vars and add it to the context:

```
class YourNamedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'a_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(YourNamedView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'var1': self.kwargs.get('var1', None),
            'var2': self.kwargs.get('var2', None),
        })
        return context
```

and in the template:

```
<h1>{{ var1 }} {{ var2 }}</h1>
```

Comment: I am getting a `TypeError` that says `get_context_data() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` (I am using Django 1.4 maybe it matters in this case?)

Comment: try get_context_data(self, **kwargs): and then self.request.get instead of only request.get

Comment: no it didn't. I had to do `self.kwargs('var1')` and `context.update()` doesn't seem to exist so I just used `context['var1'] = ...`. But I am going to accept this answer.

Comment: You're right, I was typing that from memory. Anyway, context.update does exist, I just forgot the curly brackets. Also, I would use self.kwargs.get('var1', None) so it won't fail if there's no var1 there (although then it wouldn't even get there because the Url pattern wouldn't correspond). I don't know, it's just something I usually do.

Comment: well, I'd want it to fail since both vars should be present :) also, I think it's weird that `self.kwargs('var1')` contains a path param. Could you explain why? how are they related?

Comment: It's how django is built, you find your url parameters in the kwargs. Sorry I'm not an expert in Django, try digging in the different View sources and see if you can figure out the stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

From template you can access the instance of [ResolverMatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch) representing the resolved URL

```
<p>var1 value = {{ request.resolver_match.kwargs.var1 }}</p>
<p>var2 value = {{ request.resolver_match.kwargs.var2 }}</p>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for